# Add custom user information to twig service provider silex

Tags: twig, silex

I am using the silex framework for my project. I am using the SecurityServiceProvider with a custom user implementation. The login/logout works and I am able to view the correct user information in the symfony profiler (stored as a session attribute). Now I am trying to add the custom user information to the twig environment so that is is accessible from the templates. Here is what I've come up with:

```
$app['twig'] = $app->share($app->extend('twig', function($twig, $app) {
    $token = $app['security']->getToken();
    $userInfo = null;
    if (null !== $token) {
        $userInfo = $token->getUser()->getTwigInfo();
    }
    $twig->addGlobal('userinfo', $userInfo);
    return $twig;
}));
```

I am trying to extend the environment and it works, however the user information seems to be processed later and my **userinfo** attribute is always null. I guess that I have to somehow extend the twig environment later but do not know exactly how to do that. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silex gives you access to the `app` instance directly from Twig.

So you could do:

```
{{ app.security.token ? app.security.token.user.twigInfo : null }}
```

or

```
{% set userinfo = app.security.token ? app.security.token.user.twigInfo : null %}

{{ userinfo }}
```

If you prefer to handle it within your PHP code, then you can create a new definition

```
$app['userinfo'] = $app->share(function($app) {
    $token = $app['security']->getToken();

    return (null !== $token) ? $token->getUser()->getTwigInfo() : null;
}));
```

Then in your Twig template

```
{{ app.userinfo }}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! have also succeeded to do it with the before middleware, guess that your solution is cleaner though ;)